# enablejsapi as an iframe element's attribute

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

In the docs,
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Example_Video_Player_Constructors

It states:
"In this example, an `<iframe>` element on the page already defines the player with which the API will be used. Note that either the player's src URL must set the enablejsapi parameter to 1 or the `<iframe>` element's enablejsapi attribute must be set to true."

I cannot seem to get this to work. My simple test page works fine when I append ?enablejsapi=1 to the url, but it doesn't work when adding this parameter as an attribute to the iframe.

How can I enable the api using an attribute?

Thanks
-edit: Any ideas?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <title>YouTube Player API Test </title>

</head>
<body>

<iframe id="existing-iframe-example" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE" enablejsapi="1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<!--
<iframe id="existing-iframe-example" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
-->

<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var player;
 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('existing-iframe-example');
 }
</script>

<button id="playVideo" onClick="player.playVideo()">playVideo</button><br />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work with either method. Are you sure you're not missing some includes? Anyway, "1" is not the same as "true".

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. but this is how the youtube docs say to do it. Though I am not sure if this will run in the code snippet sandbox anyway. However, when brought into a stand-alone file, it will function with the second form of the iframe call.

I am trying to get the first form to work as it is spelled out in the docs.

Comment: Also, it does not work with 1, true, True, thought the docs imply that it should work with 1

Comment: I'm also seeing `enablejsapi="1"` does nothing as an iframe attribute.

Comment: It also says on the documentation:

We support the YouTube IFrame API on Stack Overflow. Google engineers monitor and answer questions with the youtube-iframe-api tag.

So we know that's a lie.

Answer (score 1):

enablejsapi as `attribute` is `true` or `false`.
enablejsapi in `url` is `1` or `0`.

So as long you use enablejsapi as **`HTML attribute`**, you have to use **`true`** or **`false`**, and not `1` or `0` as in url.

Comment: As stated in the comment above, "Also, it does not work with 1, true, True, thought the docs imply that it should work with 1 "